# Another way of saying "it doesn't always pay to be right"

Tags: phrase-requests

Someone was wrong about something. I explained to the person very kindly and with "social tact" how they were wrong and why the right answer was, in fact, the right answer. Subsequently this person became passive aggressive in their actions. Now, I am explaining to a third party what occurred.

I am upset at the outcome and want to tell the third party that I should have just let the mistake go because *it doesn't always pay to be right*, since the result has actually made it more difficult for me.

What's another way to say *it doesn't always pay to be right*? Is there something a bit more formal?

Comment: I use [this](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/bc/bc77c796158c48caf8535ea11e1ea5012ad8d16cf406b9603cbe82206059d625.jpg). but I don't know if it would count as "more formal".

Comment: @Malvolio, hey, I said I was tactful!  :-)

Comment: Maybe that was your mistake!

Comment: From the [New Living Translation of the Bible](http://www.biblestudytools.com/proverbs/17-9-compare.html):

Proverbs 17:9 (NLT) _Disregarding another person's faults preserves love; telling about them separates close friends._ (This is one side of the tension; the Author also exposed error: 'Woe to you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites!')

Comment: I think "married" is the term you're looking for.

Comment: @HotLicks, hilarious.

Comment: A word or phrase request can attract a long list of answers when it’s more of a poll or request for ideas. Neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should say, "I should learn to choose my battles wisely" or "The battle is not always to the strong" -- both ways to say that the outcome is not always fair.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that you thought that it would be helpful to the person, but of course, "no good deed ever goes unpunished."

Answer (score 1):

What was your motivation?  If you take a look at the answers given so far, you'll see that they actually span a wide range of interpretations by presupposing different motivations: "good deed", "prophesy", "unwise battle".

With the information you've given so far, the only thing we know is that you consider your attempt a mistake.  But that's information that the person you are talking to already has and you likely want to add something.

If you don't actually want to add anything else, "choosing your battles wisely" seems to fit best so far even though it does not appear like you even intended for this to be a battle.

So a bit more neutral would be something like "I should have known better than to know better" though it's ad-hoc rather than an established saying.

Comment: Good answer, user146201. Welcome to English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 0):

"A prophet is without honor in his own land."

"You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink."

"Inconvenient truth"